# Woocommerce add img tag on order admin details page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-admin

I have a wordpress website where customers make an image with text and icons, once processed thru woocommerce and payed for that image name `12345.png` is saved as Customer_product_image

```
function add_order_item_meta($item_id, $values) {
    $key = 'customer_product_image'; // Define your key here
    $value = $values['user_img']; // Get your value here
    woocommerce_add_order_item_meta($item_id, $key, $value);
}
```

And i works great, but now i'm banning my head against the wall! When the purchased image is displayed on the Order admin detail page, it shows up as `CUSTOMER_PRODUCT_IMAGE: 1234.png` how on earth would i go about wrapping that within an image tag so the image is displayed there?

I've searched high and low on google but haven't been able to find anything, its probably that i dont know what do actually search for....

Answer (score 0):

You can use the filter `woocommerce_order_item_display_meta_value` to output the image.  Place this code in your functions.php file, you'll need to modify the src attribute of the img tag to include the appropriate URL before the filename value.  You can also modify the display label with the filter `woocommerce_order_item_display_meta_key`

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_display_meta_value', 'modify_order_item_display_value' , 10, 3 );

function modify_order_item_display_value( $display_value, $meta, $wc_order_item ) {
    $meta_data = $meta->get_data();

    if( $meta_data['key'] === 'customer_product_image' ) {
        return '<img src="' . $meta_data['value'] . '">';
    }

    return $display_value;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_order_item_display_meta_key', 'modify_order_item_display_key', 10, 3);

function modify_order_item_display_key( $display_key, $meta, $wc_order_item ) {
    $meta_data = $meta->get_data();

    if( $meta_data['key'] === 'customer_product_image' ) {
        return 'Customer Image';
    }

    return $display_key;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to share that code snippet :)

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick for me!

First i added this snippet for removing the custom meta item on order detail render:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_hidden_order_itemmeta', 'hide_order_item_meta_fields' );

function hide_order_item_meta_fields( $fields ) {
$fields[] = 'current_view';
$fields[] = 'custom_image';//Add all meta keys to this array,so that it will not be displayed in order meta box
return $fields;
}
```

second i added it back with this, and with the desired text and image tag:

```
 add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_itemmeta', 'order_meta_customized_display',10, 3 );


 function order_meta_customized_display( $item_id, $item, $product ){
  $all_meta_data=get_metadata( 'order_item', $item_id, "", "");
  $useless = array(
  "_qty","_tax_class","_variation_id","_product_id","_line_subtotal","_line_total","_line_subtotal_tax","_line_tax","_line_tax_data"
  );// Add key values that you want to ignore

  $customized_array= array();
  foreach($all_meta_data as $data_meta_key => $value) {
    if(!in_array($data_meta_key,$useless)){
      $newKey = ucwords(str_replace('_'," ",$data_meta_key ));//To remove underscrore and capitalize
      $customized_array[$newKey]=ucwords(str_replace('_'," ",$value[0])); // Pushing each value to the new array
      }
    }

  if (!empty($customized_array)) {
    foreach($customized_array as $data_meta_key => $value){

    echo "<div class='product_container'><span>Produkt Billede: </span><img src='".wp_upload_dir()['baseurl'].'/flapper/'. $value ."' /> </div>";
        }
    }
 }
```

i found the answer to this question on this [page](https://blackandwhiteshades.wordpress.com/2015/07/31/customize-woocommerce-admin-order-item-meta/)

Comment: My solution is more succinct and uses the appropriate filters provided by WooCommerce.  That article was written back in 2015, WooCommerce has changed a lot since then.